# New to Ubuntu. Can't connect to Wifi, only ethernet

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, ethernet

New to Ubuntu.  Trying to connect to wifi, can only connect on ethernet.  Saw this post
[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)
which introduced me to this script download

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

and told me to post outputs to here.  What do I need to do to fix this?
Pastebin output:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24919052/

Comment: you need the drivers forthe wifi card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install bcmwl-kernel-source,

Do:

```
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot

Comment: I've run through this tutorial, https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers
and still can't see any of my wireless network options.  I'm on the Broadcom Wireless Card 14e4:432b] (rev 01); I've tried updating my packages and PCI.IDs, removing and reinstalling my bcwml-kernel-source driver and rebooting, nothing seems to be working. Who do I ask for help?